# How can I access props for computed in Vue Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to get props data for my computed. This is the code

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    color: String,
    shape: String,
  },
  computed: {
    theme(): string {
      const args: string[] = props.color.split('-') //Cannot find name 'props'
      let var_1:string = args[0]

      return var_1
    }  
  }
})
</script>
```

I try to use "this.color" and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing through `this` is correct, but Typescript complains because `this.color` might be undefined. You can either set the property to required, or have your computed `theme` deal with undefined.

Here it is with a required color:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    color: {required: true, type: String}, // <--- make color required
    shape: String,
  },
  computed: {
    theme(): string {
      const args: string[] = this.color.split('-') // <--- access with `this`
      let var_1:string = args[0]

      return var_1
    }  
  }
})
</script>
```

or you can deal with undefined values with something like:

```
    theme(): string {
      return this.color?.split('-')[0] ?? ''
    }
```